# Creating a Java method with running time O(nlog(n))

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, runtime

I am trying to create a method which computes the union of an array of doubly linked lists. I have a method union(DLLSet s) which i can use if needed, it has a running time of O(m) where m is the sum of the sizes of the 2 DLLs. 
I am now trying to create a method which **non-recursively** finds the union of an array of DLLs in time O(nlog(n)), where n is the size of the array. Also, there is some constant c upper bounding the size of each DLL.

This is my attempt:

```
public static DLLSet fastUnion(DLLSet[] sArray){
    DLLSet set1 = sArray[0];
    for (int i=1; i<sArray.length/2 + 1; i*=2)
        for (int j=i; j<sArray.length; j += 2*i)
            set1 = set1.union(sArray[j]);
    return set1;                            
}
```

I think this code has run time O(n^2), but I have no other idea. I have a feeling I must use a merge sort algorithm and split the array into subarrays of 2, but I don't know how to implement that in this case.

**Edit:** the union is a DLL that contains the elements in 2 or more DLLs (no repeats), and I am trying to calculate the union of an array containing multiple DLLs.

Comment: What do you mean by UNION? Actually it is required to have at least two sets of something to find their union :) you've got just a single array

Comment: I edited, sorry for not clarifying what a union is! I have an array of sets

Comment: You should make the following clearer: (1) this is a homework assignment (fine, but best to be up front), and (2) what the constraints are for this assignment.

Comment: I'm sorry I honestly didn't know I had to mention it, this is my first post. what do you mean by constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just merge all DLL Sets into one large set and remove duplicates

Comment: @user3334851 if we assume that values of DLLSet elements have a specific range, we will be able to detect duplicates in linear time and constant space complexity

Comment: @user3334851 alternatively we may sort that large set, in that case we can remove duplicates without extra space. but time complexity becomes O(n*logn) where n=n1+n2+..nm, sum of sizes of DLL sets

Comment: hmmm but we would have to re-sort the DLLSet after combining the array, and that would take a lot of time wouldn't it?

Comment: @user3334851 I mean we combine all DLL sets into one array, and sort that large array

Comment: but a DLLSet is one single doubly linked list, the array is what contains the multiple doubly linked lists

Comment: @user3334851 not a big deal, you may merge doubly-linked lists into one by simple pointer manipulation and sort it :)

Comment: right, just point tail.previous of the preceding DLL with head.next of the proceeding DLL correct? but I am unsure how to sort an array like this, all the arrays I have dealt with have been in ascending order. I also have a strong feeling that sorting the array might require O(n^2)

Comment: @user3334851 there are several O(n*logn) comparison-based sorting algorithms

Comment: but don't they require recursion?

Comment: @user3334851 whatever they require, more important is that they do their job in O(n*logn) time :)

Comment: I agree, but I have a specific constraint stating that the method has to be non-recursive. I have already used recursion to implement this

Comment: @user3334851 including all its subproblems? O_o

Comment: what? :P its alright tho I realized how to use mergesort and got it :)